# How to add a Fragment's argument item to Koin dependency graph?

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, koin

I have a `ViewModel` which has a dependency which should be taken from the `Fragment`'s `arguments`.

So its something like:

```
class SomeViewModel(someValue: SomeValue)
```

now the fragment recieves the `SomeValue` in its arguemnt like so:

```
class SomeFragment : Fragment() {
    val someViewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModel()

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(someValue: SomeValue) = SomeFragment().apply {
            arguments = bundleof("someKey" to someValue)
        }
    }
}
```

problem is I don't know how to add `SomeValue` thats taken from the `Fragment`'s `arguments` to `Koin`'s module.

Is there a way to make the fragment contribute to the Koin Dependency Graph?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

So for anyone else asking the same question, here is the answer:

https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-core/injection-parameters

So basically,

you could create your module like so:

```
val myModule = module {
    viewModel { (someValue : SomeValue) -> SomeViewModel(someValue ) }
}
```

Now in your fragment, you could do something like:

```
class SomeFragment : Fragment() {
    val someViewModel: SomeViewModel by viewModel { 
        parametersOf(argument!!.getParcelable<SomeValue>("someKey")) 
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(someValue: SomeValue) = SomeFragment().apply {
            arguments = bundleof("someKey" to someValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: New URL: https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-core/injection-parameters

Comment: Thanks a ton!!! Do you happen to know if (for the scenario above) `parametersOf(this)` can be used? I do not understand this construct. Is it mapping by name or should I call some setParameter before I'm using view model?

Comment: can you clarify your question more so I could answer it better??

Comment: But what will it look like if the viewModel also receives single dependencies, such as repository?

Comment: Even newer URL  https://insert-koin.io/docs/reference/koin-android/viewmodel#viewmodel-and-injection-parameters